# Maven - FindBugs Plugin - Exclude from Test Phase

Tags: maven, findbugs, pom.xml

I have the findbugs plugin working fine in my maven setup.  I've setup findbugs to execute during the compile phase.  I noticed however that it runs during the test phase as well because the test phase also calls compile.  Because I have an automated build pipeline that runs all my targets, I don't need findbugs to run during the test phase.  I've tried to exclude findbugs from the test phase with the following but no luck yet.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>${findbugs.failOnError}</failOnError>
        <skip>${findbugs.skip}</skip>
        <trace>${findbugs.trace}</trace>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>findbugs-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not be called based on the running through the life-cylcle via compile it simply is running cause you configured to have two executions one in test and one in compile phase. Findbugs should usually run in the reporting area(site).
Just make a single execution:

```
  <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>findbugs-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

The one you like to have. But i recommend to read the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin-2.4.0/usage.html) cause it should run in reporting area (via site) only.

**UPDATE:**
If you like to run findbugs only during the site generation than just remove it from the usual build area and put into the reporting area instead.

Comment: I had this problem of findbugs running on the test phase with that 2nd <execution> section.  I added the 2nd <execution> so that I could set it to <skip> the test phase.  In other words, if I remove the 2nd <execution> with the test phase in it, findbugs will still run if I issue mvn test.

Comment: The question is why would you like to run findbugs during compile cycle? The usual use case is to run it during the site generation. The simple questions is: When would you like to run findbugs ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to discuss this.  I want to run it during compile so the build can fail if new bugs are found.  Site generation is not part of the normal setup.  I only generate the site if everything builds and passes all the tests correctly.  Note that my work is not a "site" but a back end server so site is strictly used in my case to generate the project information and reporting.

Comment: Based on that i would say you should use the phase "process-classes" which if after compile.